# Is there anything we can change all Kendo MVC UI testboxes maximum character in one shot?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have so many **kendo MVC UI textboxes and numerictextbox**  **maximum character** property in easy way ,

what are all the ways present to solve this

CODE:

there are so many text and numeric boxes like this

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyTypeName).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50px", @maxlength = "5" }).Name("CompanyTypeName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using Editor Templates. Then you can make a single change to, for example, your String.cshtml file and all your EditorFor lines for string properties will utilize the same code.

Your code example above would change to:

```
@Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.CompanyTypeName)
```

Then, you can add a String.cshtml file to your Shared/EditorTemplates folder that looks something like:

```
@model object

@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50px", @maxlength = "5" })
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but following the procedure you told will also take lot of time in our project. I will look into it.

Comment: understood, then you're probably looking at doing a Find and Replace in Visual Studio using regular expressions to find all the instances of "TextBoxFor" and "HtmlAttributes" followed by "@maxlength = "  and updating the maxlength number in the quotes. That is doable, once you figure out the regex